# PDO get entire row after insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building the request new password functionality and for the purpose I have created a separate table called `users_forgotpasscodes` which consists of 3 fields `user_id`, `code` and `requested`. Codes will be sent to users' emails and will be valid 1 day. I decided to go with a separate table instead of creating an extra column in my users table because I suppose a very little amount of users will be using this function so it makes no sense to have all users have an attribute that they will probably not use.

Anyway what I stumbled upon is when the user goes to the "forgot my password" page and enters his email address this is what happens

```
self::$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users_forgotpasscodes (id, code, requested) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?), '{$code}', NOW())")->execute([$data['email']])
```

The problem is that I further down in this code I need the user's ID in order to be able to navigate them accurately from their inbox to the correct page to create a new password.

My question is can I retrieve the entire row that I have inserted without making another select query?

The tricky part is that I can't use `lastInsertId()` because column `id` in the codes table is not primary key it is just an ordinary index because one user can send multiple requests of this nature and I want to be able to keep track of them.

Comment: What you mean by `entire row`? You only want to return `ID` column?

Comment: @Rahul yeah basically if I find out how to get the entire row I will be able to get the id, I used this title to avoid confusion with `lastInsertId` and to be easier to find if someone is searching for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not absolutely sure but from your comment, it looks like you just want to return the `ID` column (which is not a `auto_increment` field) of the last inserted row.

In that case, have the `INSERT` operation through a stored procedure and use a `OUTPUT` parameter to get the inserted `ID` value. Then you can use the same anywhere in your application code. A sample code below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Insert(
IN col1 VARCHAR(25),
IN col2 VARCHAR(10),
IN email VARCHAR(30),
OUT ret_ID INT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO your_table(ID,col1,col2) VALUES(ID,col1,col2);

SELECT ID INTO ret_ID FROM your_table where Email = email; <-- assign here
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call your procedure from application code and fetch the `ret_ID`

```
CALL sp_Insert(1, 'blah', 'blah blah', @ret);

SELECT @ret;
```

Comment: Just if you can save me some time, since I'm not very good with procedures - I don't have the ID as an in parameter I have the email so I need to get the id corresponding to that email and save it in a variable in the procedure, but then how do I assign the out parameter to be that variable?

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` condition, like `select ID into out_parameter from some_table where email = email_parameter`. About how you call it in PHP and save the OUT parameter value -- I am pretty sure you have lots of example out there in internet. I can't help in there cause I have no idea about PHP. Answered solely cause the question is related to SQL.

Comment: No, no I meant inside of the procedure code. I have to assign the id to a variable because I need to use it once in the insert statement and then return it, so I guess it will look something like `@id = SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = IN_EMAIL` if that is even the syntax to define a variable inside a procedure. So then to return the variable I need to use something like `SELECT @id INTO ret_ID`?

Comment: But then where does `ID` come from in the `VALUES` section of the insert statement?

Comment: Hey, that's just a sample procedure code to let you know the way. don't relate with your actual code/scenario.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. I will be accepting this answer if no better one is given soon.